# Copy/Pasting large amounts of data from term server to Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, copy-paste

So, here's the issue.  I'm copying the XML contents formatted as one line of text (some with a datalength of over 200k, so over 100k of characters) of an NText field from SQL Server on a term server into Notepad++ locally, and it's truncating part of the value.  I've tested pasting the same data into Google Sheets locally with no issue, so I know it's not a term server clipboard limit, and what I'm finding by searching google, is that Notepad++ is supposed to handle pasting 10 million rows of data, and people have had no problem pasting that very large amounts of data in one line in Notepad++ either.

Anybody have any suggestions on what the issue is?  I'm using Notepad++ version 7.8.9

Answer (score 0):

Azure.com suggests this as the reason for this, and a character count in Notepad++ confirms this:

> > 65,535 characters Confirmed as still an OPEN issue in SQL Server Management Studio 2014 (version 12.0. 2000.8). When copying a cell in
> > the results grid that contains a large character string, the text is
> > truncated to 43,679 characters, even when SSMS is configured to
> > retrieve a maximum of 65,535 characters.Aug 21, 2014
>
> SSMS - Can not paste more than 43679 characters from a ...